# ObjWorkbook.Worksheets.Count not working

Tags: excel, vba, count, vbscript, runtime-error

I am trying to write a code to open an Excel file and then search through it. Even though, I am having problems just retrieving the number of worksheets in the workbook. I get the error:

> 424 - VBScript Runtime Error, Object Required

Any thoughts? Here is the small portion of the code I am having problems with:

```
Dim Shell : Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Dim oFSO : Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objExcel : Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim myworkbook, worksheetcount
Set myworkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Test.xlsx")

On Error Resume Next
Set worksheetcount = myworkbook.worksheets.count 'fails

If Err.number <> 0 Then
    ShowError()
    myworkbook.Close False
End if

Sub ShowError()
    WScript.Echo Err.Number & " Srce: " & Err.Source & " Desc: " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would do the job.

**VBA version**

```
Dim Shell As Object: Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim oFSO As Object: Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objExcel As Application: Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim myworkbook As Workbook, worksheetcount As Long
Set myworkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Test.xlsx")

On Error Resume Next
worksheetcount = myworkbook.Worksheets.Count

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ShowError
    myworkbook.Close False
End If
```

**VBScript version**

```
Dim Shell: Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim oFSO: Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objExcel: Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim myworkbook, worksheetcount
Set myworkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Test.xlsx")

On Error Resume Next
worksheetcount = myworkbook.Worksheets.Count

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ShowError
    myworkbook.Close False
End If
```

You had error, because you tried to `Set` a value to `worksheetcount` which is not an object. You use `Set` only to objects.

Comment: I would also recommend not using the `:` to have multiple statements on one line. It's legal, but it's easy for humans to skip over it and not see potentially vital code.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that. But, do you have any idea why wouldn't it let me declare variables with its types? It now gives me an error since line 1.

Comment: On line 1 I also replaced `WScript.CreateObject()` with just `CreateObject()`, as I had errors before. Try changing it back.

Comment: It does not work either. While building by bigger code I also had to get rid of Dim myworkbook As Workbook, as it would not compile. Could there be any other factors affecting this?

Comment: I thought you were working on VBA, but it seems it's VBScript, so all those explicit declarations do not work in VBScript!

Comment: That would explain it! Yes, I am using VBSCRIPT, with Excel 97-2003.